# Use glom to get Index while iterating over an list of dictionaries

Tags: python, glom

```
from glom import glom, T
from glom.core import Val


target = [
    {"firstname": 'boka', 'lastname':'raton'},
    {"firstname": 'cape', 'lastname':'town'}
]
spec = ([{
    'fname':'firstname',
    'index': Val('0')
}])

r = glom(target, spec)
print(r)
```

Is it possible to capture the index while iterating over a list of dictionaries using glom?
The current output is:

```
[{'fname': 'boka', 'index': '0'}, {'fname': 'cape', 'index': '0'}].
```

But I'd like to have the following:

```
[{'fname': 'boka', 'index': 0}, {'fname': 'cape', 'index': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by enumerating over the items and performing glom on one dictionary at a time.
Used the `Val` to evaluate the wrapped value of `index`

```
from glom import glom
from glom.core import Val
result = []
for index, value in enumerate(target):
    spec = {
        'fname': 'firstname',
        'index': Val(index)
    }
    r = glom(value, spec)
    result.append(r)
print(result)
```